# Hardware board receives extra null character before receiving the actual data

Tags: android, sockets, hardware

I am using texas instruments TM4C123G launchpad board connected to wifi shield and used to control the light by android app. when i send a command over wifi using simple socket at receiving side i am getting a null character i.e. <0> before an actual data. so my question is Is TCP/IP protocol adds extra null character before sending the data.

Comment: Try to test with different parties, replace the launchpad with a simple listener, for example.

Comment: @GaborSch thanks for reply but i solved it..it was because of different size of character data types on java and on Board..

Comment: nice solution! \o/

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP is just a transport protocol.  Implementations of the protocol are unlikely to add padding of any kind, to the transported data.

I am not familiar with that particular board, so I can only offer a guess.  The nulls could be coming from any of a number of places:

1. The sensor may send a null when it is not reading any value
2. The sensor is probably connected to the launch board on a USB bus. 
   The board may read no sample on the bus as a null value
3. The application on the launch board, that is preparing the data for transfer over the WiFi connection, might be padding the data, or that null may be part of its protocol

My guess would be #3.  If the null is really a problem and it is possible to do so, I would start by seeing if you can see it on the launch board side, before the data is packaged for transmission.